# How do I prevent my sprite from going behind the tilemap whilst patrolling?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Whenever I enter play mode, my patrolling enemy moves as expected but it's sprite is partially behind the tilemap. I can still interact with the game object. The Z position for my enemy is closer to the camera than the tilemap as well as the two points the enemy moves between.

This is the code I used
[image]

This is the issue I'm having
[image]

From what was shown when the code was originally used, the object just moved back and forth between the two points in the same z position as before.

Comment: You should have a look at the sprite renderer and then "Additional Settings" => "Sorting Layer". With these layers you can change the sorting order and your enemy will always be in front of the background.

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple reasons for your problem.

At first check the "Sorting Layer" and Order in Layer. These Settings are found inside the Renderer's property settings. Set the Renderer to an existing Sorting Layer or create a new one to determine its priority in the rendering queue. Also make sure to set the "Order in Layer", whenever using the same Sorting Layer.

[Example Sprite Renderer](https://docs.unity3d.com/uploads/Main/2D_SpriteRenderer_1.png)

[Read more about Tilemap Renderer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TilemapRenderer.html)

Also the distance to camera can cause some trouble. If the camera option is set to Perspective, the sorting distance of a Renderer is the direct distance of the renderer from the camera's position.